# How to get all os installed in a computer using C#?

Tags: c#, operating-system

all

I am trying to detect all operating system name and version from a computer using C#.

For example, if a user installed Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 in one computer.

I will have to get 2 items with os names and versions.

I have searched google, but I cannot find any information about this.

Any has any idea how to approach?

Comment: Check all files on hdd / ssd and check if they are is files. Then check version number if able.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
OSInfo.Name
```

This will give you the name of the operating system.

```
OSInfo.Edition
```

This will give you the edition.

```
OSInfo.VersionString
```

This will give you the version.

I'm sure you can play around with this to get what you want.

Comment: That's for current OS, isn't it? My question was to find out all OS installed in a computer.